# Как ускорить поиск изображения через locateCenterOnScreen

Tags: python, pyautogui

День добрый. Написал на питоне простой код для поиска и нажатия на кнопку на экране:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.sleep(5)
while True:
    coord = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r"D:\all\ms1.png", confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.click(coord)
```

находит верно, нажимает верно, но вот только кнопка двигается, а у данного метода поиска есть задержка +- пол секунды при разрешении 1920x1080, при снижении разрешения, понятно, что находит быстрее, но хочется что бы находило в 1920x1080. Можно как-то ускорить поиск? есть альтернативы?

Answer (score -1):

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    button_location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(r"D:\all\ms1.png", confidence=0.9)
    if button_location:
        x, y, width, height = button_location
        pyautogui.click(x + width/2, y + height/2)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Есть метод для получения точки по центру: `pyautogui.center`. А как ваш ответ поможет автору ускорить поиск картинки на экране? :)